# Remove "\r" from echoing out in bash script

Tags: bash

Here is my Bash script that is sent a variable from PHP:

```
STRING1="/opt/lampp/htdocs/dev/img/$VAR1"
mv $STRING1 "/opt/lampp/htdocs/dev/newlocation/"
```

It, for some reason, places `\r` at the end of `$STRING1` and can’t find the file because it will be something of the form `my_picture.jpg\r`.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Bash expects that end-of-line in a script is always and only a newline (`\n`) character, Unix-style, not a carriage return-newline combination (`\r\n`) like you normally see on Windows. Bash thinks the `\r` character is just an ordinary character at the end of the string.  (Characters that follow a double quoted string are just concatenated onto the end.)

As Ignacio suggests, the solution is to fix your script to eliminate the `\r` characters. `dos2unix` is one way.   Another would be to use `tr -d '\r' < infile > outfile` as a filter.

Answer (score 15):

This is obviously for the purpose of other googlers like me, not the OP, seeing that it's been 5+ years. But this solution existed back then too.

You can try a bash substitution to strip the largest pattern from the end of the string which looks like ${varname%%pattern}, more here:

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html

It should be faster than spawning another process like tr to handle it.

```
VARNAME=$'a_bad_filename\r'
VARNAME="${VARNAME%%[[:cntrl:]]}"
```

Here is a reference for the [severely-limited bash pattern matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html) (it is not really regular expression, more of a 'like' or 'glob' expression). As to why the carriage return is in the control class and not the whitespace class, I'm not sure. It is considered white-space in other languages. Without enabling extended pattern matching via a "shopt -s extglob", there's no way to specify a simple construct like "this char repeated 0 or more times" in bash. I also found

```
printf "%q" "${VARNAME}"
```

.. in addition to `set -vx` to show/test for the carriage return.

I came across this problem when using cygwin bash against output from the standard (non-cygwin) version of python; I'm confused as to why I'm not seeing more on how to solve it.

Comment: it works when I get a tool's version from a docker image, great

Comment: it works, and is better for my one line script

Comment: I'd give you 50 points if I could.

Answer (score 10):

Pass the script through `dos2unix` to fix the newlines.

Comment: And then switch to a text editor that doesn't use DOS-style line endings.